# Removing duplicate values from an array

Tags: java, array

Here is my code for removing duplicated values from an array. I think I tested it with the most possible cases. Any suggestions or bugs?

```
class duplicate {

    public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] arr) { 
        int end = arr.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < end; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {                  
                    int shiftLeft = j;

                    for(int k = j + 1; k < end; k++, shiftLeft++) {
                        arr[shiftLeft] = arr[k];
                    }

                    end--;
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }

        int[] whitelist = new int[end];

        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
            whitelist[i] = arr[i];
        }

        return whitelist;
    }
}
```

After some tests, it appears really inefficient because an array with 1,000,000 elements takes a very long time to end. Is there any better way to implement this on arrays?

Comment: Use Set(Eg HashSet). Duplicate values are not allowed in it. Just iterate over the array and add it to the Set.If you want result in an array copy the set to the target array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're following the same philosophy as the bubble sort, which is very, very, very slow. Have you tried this?:

- Sort your unordered array with [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). Quicksort is much faster than bubble sort (I know, you are not sorting, but the algorithm you follow is almost the same as bubble sort to traverse the array).
- Then start removing duplicates (repeated values will be next to each other). In a `for` loop you could have two indices: `source` and `destination`. (On each loop you copy `source` to `destination` unless they are the same, and increment both by 1). Every time you find a duplicate you increment source (and don't perform the copy).

Answer (score 11):

Suggestion:

```
public static Integer[] removeDuplicates(Integer[] arr) {
  return new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr)).toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```

Another solution might be:

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] arr) {
  Set<Integer> alreadyPresent = new HashSet<Integer>();
  int[] whitelist = new int[0];

  for (int nextElem : arr) {
    if (!alreadyPresent.contains(nextElem)) {
      whitelist = Arrays.copyOf(whitelist, whitelist.length + 1);
      whitelist[whitelist.length - 1] = nextElem;
      alreadyPresent.add(nextElem);
    }
  }

  return whitelist;
}
```

Here you only iterate once via `arr`.

Comment: You could avoid copying the whitelist for every unique element, and start it off by having the same size as the original, then only copy the subarray with unique lements just before returning.

Comment: Incrementally increasing `whitelist` by 1 creates a time complexity of **`O(N^2)`**. Consider using `ArrayList` which expands dynamically, and returning `arraylist.toArray();` That would run in **`O(N)`**.

Comment: @awashburn if targeting >= .NET 2.0, one should use `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 10):

A slight improvement on Dr H's

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    Set<Integer> alreadyPresent = new HashSet<>();
    int[] whitelist = new int[arr.length];
    int i = 0;

    for (int element : arr) {
        if (alreadyPresent.add(element)) {
            whitelist[i++] = element;
        }
    }

    return Arrays.copyOf(whitelist, i);
}
```

This does only one array copy at the end. It also takes advantage of the fact that `Set.add()` returns a boolean that indicated if the Set changed, and so avoids an explicit `contains()` check.

**Java 8 update**

In java 8 the code is a lot simpler :

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
            .distinct()
            .toArray();
}
```

Comment: why you are copying whitelist ? Can't we just return whitelist ?

Comment: @PrabhatSubedi copy because the size will (most likely) be smaller than the original. And whitelist has the original size.